# How to do subquery with multiple columns as alias

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two SQL tables, "Debits", and "Debits_Line_Items." I would like to run a SQL query of the "Debits" table, where each debit record contains a list of corresponding records in the "Debits_Line_Items" table, which should match on the CartID value.

This is what I've tried, which produced an error that column "lineItems" is unknown:

```
SELECT 
    CartID AS cartId,
    TotalCost AS totalCost,
    lineItems
FROM Debits
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            Price AS cost,
            Quantity AS quantity,
            TotalPrice as total 
        FROM Debits_Line_Items
        WHERE UserID = 9902
    ) AS lineItems
ON Debits.CartID = lineItems.CartID
WHERE UserID = 9902
```

This is what I'm hoping for:

```
   [
      {
        cartId: 3225,
        totalCost: 212,
        lineItems: [
          {
             cost: 32,
             quantity: 1, 
             total: 32
          }, 
          {
             cost: 60,
             quantity: 3, 
             total: 180
          },          
       },
       {
        cartId: 3226,
        totalCost: 75,
        lineItems: [
          {
             cost: 15,
             quantity: 5, 
             total: 75
          }         
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? did you want to get json string from mysql?

Comment: What's your mysql version ?

Comment: Can you share the table structure of the tables used here?

Comment: You have not selected `CartID` column from the table `Debits_Line_Items`. Then only you can use `ON Debits.CartID = lineItems.CartID`

Comment: lineitems is a sub query alias not a column name. Your select should be refer to all the column names by name (lineitmes.<column>) or all lineitems.*

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
WITH lineItems(cost, quantity, total, CartID) AS (
     SELECT 
           Price AS cost,
           Quantity AS quantity,
           TotalPrice as total 
      FROM 
            Debits_Line_Items
      WHERE 
            UserID = 9902
)
SELECT 
      d.CartID AS cartId,
      d.TotalCost AS totalCost,
      lineItems.*
FROM  
      Debits d
LEFT JOIN lineItems l
  ON d.CartID = l.CartID
WHERE 
      d.UserID = 9902
```

Let me know if it helps. Always best to link with rextester. Then we can validate code for you with some sample data.